# Update child components based on parent state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react, I'm running into what I'm pretty sure is a common problem with a common solution but, because I'm new to the idea of React, I have no idea how to solve it.

Using the following as an example, how can I get my children to re-render whenever the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` callbacks are called? (Don't tell me to use a different component, this idea can be applied to lots of parent-child relationships - when something happens on a parent, re-render the children).

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPressIn={() => { /* what do I do here */ }}
    onPressOut={() => { /* what do I do here */ }}
>
    <View
        style={{
            backgroundColor: /* if touchable is highlighted black, otherwise white */
        }}
    >
        <Text
            style={{
                color: /* if selected, then white, otherwise, black */
            }}
        >
            Some Text
        </Text>
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

It seems a bit verbose to have to write custom components (so I can just call `setState()` every time I need this kind of functionality, do I really have to?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onPressIn()` and `onPressOut()` methods should update the state of your component.  When a component's state is changed, the `render()` method is called and the component is re-rendered.  If the component's children's properties have changed due to the update in state, then they will be re-rendered as well.

In your specific case you should do the following:

1. Add  a state to your component.  Somewhere in the component definition add `state = { pressed: false }`
2. Update the state with your onPress methods and use the state when setting the properties of your component's children:

```jsx
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPressIn={() => { this.setState({pressed: true}) }}
    onPressOut={() => { this.setState({pressed: false}) }}
>
    <View
        style={{
            backgroundColor: (this.state.pressed) ? 'black' : 'white'
        }}
    >
        <Text
            style={{
                color: (this.state.pressed) ? 'white' : 'black'
            }}
        >
            Some Text
        </Text>
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

The above was tested in React Native 0.48 on an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough example you would update the state on those callbacks and pass it as prop to your children components in the render method.

For example :

```
this.state = { isHighlighted: false }; // inside the parent component constructor

render() {
  const { isHighlighted } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <FirstChild style={{ backgroundColor: isHighlighted ? 'black' : 'white' }}> 
        <SecondChild style={{ color: isHighlighted ? 'white' : 'black' }}>Some text</SecondChild>
      </FirstChild>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the **callbacks** would be :

```
onPressIn={() => { this.setState({ isHighlighted: true }) }}
onPressOut={() => { this.setState({ isHighlighted: false }) }}
```

If you would want to have style through nested components you would have to :

a) keep passing them as props

b) hold your state in a store (https://github.com/reactjs/redux)

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor :

```
this.state={pressedIn:false,onPressOut:false}
```

Then

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPressIn={() => { this.setState({pressedIn:true,pressedOut:false}}
    onPressOut={() => { {this.setState({pressedOut:true,pressedIn:false}}
>
    <View
        style={{
            backgroundColor: this.state.pressedIn? "someColor":"SomeOtherColor"
        }}
    >
        <Text
            style={{
                color: this.state.onPressOut? "someColor":"SomeOtherColor"
            }}
        >
            Some Text
        </Text>
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```